# Modify column length in MySql

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter-table, truncated

I'm issuing the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `column_name` VARCHAR(1022)
```

At the moment it's `VARCHAR(1024)`, however I'm getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1265 Data truncated for column mysql
```

I guess it's because some rows are longer than 1022 characters. When I add `IGNORE` to the command, the command finishes successfully but these rows still have 1024 characters, mysql did not remove the last 2 characters to make it 1022, is there any way to force this so that to ensure that all rows end up with the new column size?

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `e_entity` (
`OID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`E_E_OID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`UNIQUE_IDX` int(11) NOT NULL,
`APP_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`META_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`STORE_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
`REL_DISPLAY` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX01` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX02` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX03` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX04` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX05` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX06` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX07` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX08` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX09` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`SINDEX10` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`NINDEX01` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX02` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX03` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX04` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX05` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX06` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX07` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX08` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX09` double NOT NULL,
`NINDEX10` double NOT NULL,
`DINDEX01` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX02` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX03` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX04` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX05` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX06` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX07` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX08` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX09` datetime NOT NULL,
`DINDEX10` datetime NOT NULL,
`FREETEXT` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`UID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`OID`),
KEY `App_Parent` (`META_OID`),
KEY `RelDisplay` (`REL_DISPLAY`),
KEY `sindex01` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX01`(64)),
KEY `sindex02` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX02`(64)),
KEY `sindex03` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX03`(64)),
KEY `sindex04` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX04`(64)),
KEY `sindex05` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX05`(64)),
KEY `sindex06` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX06`(64)),
KEY `sindex07` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX07`(64)),
KEY `sindex08` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX08`(64)),
KEY `sindex09` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX09`(64)),
KEY `sindex10` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX10`(64)),
KEY `nindex01` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX01`),
KEY `nindex02` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX02`),
KEY `nindex03` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX03`),
KEY `nindex04` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX04`),
KEY `nindex05` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX05`),
KEY `dindex01` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX01`),
KEY `dindex02` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX02`),
KEY `dindex03` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX03`),
KEY `dindex04` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX04`),
KEY `dindex05` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX05`),
KEY `nindex06` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX06`),
KEY `nindex07` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX07`),
KEY `nindex08` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX08`),
KEY `nindex09` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX09`),
KEY `nindex10` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX10`),
KEY `dindex06` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX06`),
KEY `dindex07` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX07`),
KEY `dindex08` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX08`),
KEY `dindex09` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX09`),
KEY `dindex10` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX10`),
KEY `E_E_OID` (`E_E_OID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=469158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Comment: You may try to trim values before altering column. `UDATE 'table_name' SET 'column_name'=LEFT('column_name', 1022)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your MySQL server is running in [SQL strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

There is mention about effects  of this mode on [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) execution:

> When you change a data type using CHANGE or MODIFY, MySQL tries to
>   convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible.
>
> This conversion may result in alteration of data. **For example, if you
>   shorten a string column, values may be truncated. To prevent the
>   operation from succeeding if conversions to the new data type would
>   result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode** before using ALTER
>   TABLE

I would try to change SQL mode at runtime based on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) (you may need SUPER privilege - not sure):

> To change the SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session sql_mode
>   system variable using a SET statement:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

Then repeat your ALTER statement.

Comment: You mean `SET SESSION sql_mode = ''` ?